# Need small clarification regarding this use of 遊び

Tags: translation, usage

I was translating some lines earlier and I ran into a snag after the speaker said this:

その言葉は重くて、遊びで戦っているのではない事だけは俺にも伝わりました。

My main problem comes from the 遊びで戦っている part and I'd like to confirm that I'm reading this right.

What I'm seeing is that the speaker's saying that that he understood, from a mentor's words (that he overheard a few seconds ago), that they are fighting despite not liking it?

Addendum: Or it also mean that they're not fighting as a game/for the hell of it? Because the whole point of this scene is that the speaker has realized that everyone around him has a reason to why they're fighting in the first place.

Is this interpretation correct?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latter interpretation is correct. "遊びで戦っているのではない" basically means "本気で戦っている". Without context, it is hard to infer whether they like the fight or not, though.